# CICS TS(DFHJS2LS): Chinese characters are getting corrupted when received into MAINFRAME from POSTMAN tool

Tags: json, utf-8, cjk, cics

We have developed a webservice having CICS as the HTTP SERVER (service provider). This Webservice takes the input JSON (which has both English and Chinese characters) from any client/POSTMAN tool and will be processed in Mainframe (CICS).

**DFHJS2LS: JSON schema to high-level language conversion for request-response services**

We are using this proc - DFHJS2LS to enable webservices in Mainframe. ThisI BM provided procedure does the conversion of JSON to MF copybook and vice-versa. Also it converts the UTF-8 code unit  into UTF-16 when it reaches mainframe copybook.

**Issue:**

The issue what we face now is on the Chinese characters. The Chinese characters which we pass in JSON are not getting converted properly and they are getting corrupted when it is received inside mainframe. The conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 is not happening (this is my suspect).

市  - this is the chinese character passed in JSON (POSTMAN).

Expected value in Mainframe copybook is 5E02(UTF-16 - hex value) 
but we got 00E5 00B8 0082(UTF-8  hex value)

we have tried all header values and still no luck.....
content type  = application/json 
charset=UTF-8 / UTF-16

Your inputs are much appreciated in addressing this DBCS/unicode/chinese character issue.

Comment: What are the results of having your CICS Systems Programmer run a trace showing the contents of your message?

Comment: Hi cschneid, thanks for responding... Even our CICS systems programmers doesnt have any clue. The Trace doesnt show any error signs. 

The conversion of UTF-8 --> UTF-16 is what is not happening

Answer (score 0):

In the COBOL are you declaring the filed that will receive the Chinese characters as Pic G :

01 China-Test-Message.
03 Msg-using-pic-x Pic X(10).
03 Msg-using-pic-g Pic G(4) Usage Display-1.

Comment: the procedure DFHJS2LS provides the copybook structure with all fields as National Datatype. and we used the same.
05  test-CHNNEL-LEN      PIC S9999 COMP-5 SYNC         
                                           VALUE 0.       
05  test-CHNNEL-NM       PIC N(20) USAGE NATIONAL      
                                           VALUE SPACES.

Answer (score 0):

Try "USAGE NATIONAL" which shoul dmap to UTF-16 which is probably the code page for the chinese character.

RTFM here:-
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_6.3.0/pg/concepts/cpuni01.html

Comment: yes, we used the same James.

the concern is the target copybook variable is of PIC clause -  NATIONAL. But our suspect is that the procedure - DFHJS2LS doesnt load the copybook fields after converting it to UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

The chinese conversion is resolved once we changed our HTTP header to this -

Content-Type = application/json;charset=UTF-8

thanks everyone for the support.